# Array Transformation to object in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Explanation:  Need to convert Array to objects, that contain information of Students `X` `Y` `Z` `total`  `math`, and `math_teach` information in one object. see the expected output as one document.

Document 1 :

```
{
  "students": [
    "X",
    "Y",
    "Z"
  ],
  "total": [
    150,
    200,
    100
  ],
  "math": [
    "A",
    "A+",
    "B+"
  ],
  "math_teach": [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
  ]

}
```

Expected Output :

```
{
"total_students" : 3,
  "X" :{
    "total" : 150,
    "math" : "A",
    "math_teach" : "A"
  },
  "Y":{
    "total" : 200,
    "math" : "A+",
    "math_teach" : "B"
  },
  "Z" : {
    "total" : 100,
    "math" : "B+",
    "math_teach" : "C"
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$size` to get total elements in `students` array
- `$map` to iterate loop of `students` array
- `$indexOfArray` to get current student index from `students` array
- `$arrayElemAt` to get above index elements from specific array like `total`, `math`
- `$arrayToObject` convert above result of key-value array of object to an object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      total_students: { $size: "$students" },
      students: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: "$students",
            in: {
              k: "$$this",
              v: {
                total: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    "$total",
                    { $indexOfArray: ["$students", "$$this"] }
                  ]
                },
                math: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    "$math",
                    { $indexOfArray: ["$students", "$$this"] }
                  ]
                },
                math_teach: {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    "$math_teach",
                    { $indexOfArray: ["$students", "$$this"] }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W4M3rEwxmdw)